# Move the SKSpriteNode to the actual touch point in ios Game

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics, skspritenode

I have a SKSpriteNode, which is a ball. My view don't have gravity. I'm able to move the ball by applying an impulse over it in the start and I want to make it to move to the user touch point which we can get in -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event method without affecting its motion.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    for (UITouch *touch in touches)
        {
            CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
            SKAction *moveToPoint = [SKAction moveByX:location.x y:location.y duration:2];

            [ball runAction:moveToPoint];
        }
}
```

Its not seems to be working. Help me guys.

Comment: Instead of moveByX:y:duration use moveTo:duration

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the node directly to a point use the method:

```
[SKAction moveTo:location duration:2];
```

The `SKAction moveBy:` method moves the node by the x and y values provided, whereas the `moveTo` method to the point in the node's parent.

EDIT:

Also, change the line:

```
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
```

to

```
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
```

A UIView has a different coordinate system than a SKScene.

EDIT 2: You can remove affect of physics while touch exists

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    for (UITouch *touch in touches)
        {
            ball.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

            CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode: self];
            SKAction *moveToPoint = [SKAction moveTo:location duration:2];

            [ball runAction:moveToPoint];
        }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    ball.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
}
```

Comment: Ball is not moving to touch point it is moving toward somewhere else. Also your code affects the moving path of ball.

Comment: Okay, so the ball is under a physics simulation as well?

Comment: Yes with no gravity, no friction, restitution  =1, no linear damping. Ball is moving because of applied initial impulse.

Comment: You can remove affect of physics on the ball while the touch exists. See edit 2

Comment: Now problem is that ball is getting bounced at touch point even though there is nothing at touch point

Comment: Same problem bro ball gets bouncing when it reaches touch point . That is my touch point acts like a static hurdle, which makes ball to bounce.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75108/discussion-between-user007007-and-zemoon).

Comment: While setting `ball.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;` also set `ball.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0,0);`